# Action is not present in standard object Product , in button ,Link, And Action Category

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, api

I need to call a Lightning component  to replace my classic salesforce javascript  button on detail page of product object.But in case of product i am not getting action from where i can call my action type as "Lightning component".Any Workaround for this, as i need to give a 3rd party api call from that lightning component.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As we can see that "Action" is not available in the Product2 Object so the work around is ,you need to edit your record page from setup and directly drag and drop your component so it will come with other standard button and it will give a call to your Aura method because Quick Action is still not available to your object.

Below is the solution implemented screen shot.

[image]